# How to request only the HTTP header with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, system.net

I want to check if the URL of a large file exists. I'm using the code below but it is too slow:

```
public static bool TryGet(string url)
{
    try
    {
        GetHttpResponseHeaders(url);
        return true;
    }
    catch (WebException)
    {
    }

    return false;
}

public static Dictionary<string, string> GetHttpResponseHeaders(string url)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    WebRequest webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        foreach (string header in webResponse.Headers)
        {
            headers.Add(header, webResponse.Headers[header]);
        }
    }

    return headers;
}
```

Comment: Do you really have to loop through all the headers?

Comment: @DOK Nope, but I doubt the headers are responsible this performance hit

Comment: This may not be the problem either, but I seen in [MSDN}(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) that You must call either the Stream.Close or the HttpWebResponse.Close method to close the response and release the connection for reuse.

Comment: @DOK I believe the `using` directive already does that for me.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to set:

```
webRequest.Method = "HEAD";
```

This way the server will respond with the header information only (no content). This is also useful to check if the server accepts certain operations (i.e. compressed data etc.).

Comment: @Liam It should, however there is no guarantee.

Comment: @Liam my experience is that it does not work on a significant number of sites, like 20%

Comment: In my case, it returns content! ContentLegnth is not -1.