# how to know if request supports resume?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am downloading a `.mp3` file and before download I want to read the header of the file to see if it can has resume support.
I read that if it has resume support it will return a response with a status code 206 but I always get status code 200 even I know it has resume support.

For getting status code I am using:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlstring);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode);
```

Do I need to add more property or try something else entirely?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to request only the HTTP header with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237734/how-to-request-only-the-http-header-with-c)

Comment: Do a `HEAD` request first, then the GET-request.

Comment: @Joel I thought I am getting head with this request I am not downloading via this code
If I am not requesting HEAD how can I request it?

Comment: I assume you are not speaking about the file header. Like the first X byte. If it's the case, You can get stream and read only the length you need. webResponse.GetResponseStream()

Comment: @xdtTransform I can read content length with the response I posted in code
but I need to know if it has resume support
if it has I can resume the download where I left if not I need to start the download from beginning

Comment: @xdtTransform I used ```request.Method = "HEAD"``` but no change in the response

Comment: @xdtTransform the answer you post works great. I didnt know that I should look for accept ranges header thanks